# C++ cin stream keep getting thread text in eclipse debug mode

Tags: c++, eclipse

The code is simple block and wait for enter from user:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Demo!!!" << endl;
    char select = 0;
while (1) {
        cout << "Enter button:" << endl;
        select = getchar(); //same issue with cin>>select;

        switch (select) {
        case 'u':
            //do st;
            break;
        case 'd':
            //do st;            
            break;
        }
        cout << "Entered: " << select << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the eclipse in debug mode does not wait for the character at all (I dont type any character yet):

```
Enter button:
Entered: 4
Enter button:
Entered: 8
Enter button:
Entered: -
Enter button:
Entered: t
Enter button:
Entered: h
Enter button:
Entered: r
Enter button:
Entered: e
Enter button:
Entered: a
Enter button:
Entered: d
Enter button:
Entered: -
Enter button:
Entered: s
Enter button:
Entered: e
Enter button:
Entered: l
Enter button:
Entered: e
Enter button:
Entered: c
Enter button:
Entered: t
Enter button:
Entered: 1
Enter button:
```

I use MINGW GCC as compiler and eclipse as IDE on window 10.
Another issue that might relevant: eclipse keep quitting spontaneously during debug (I does not found any mention in google).

Comment: Because of stuff like this, I stopped using the eclipse console and instead have eclipse spawn a system console. Make a `.gdbinit` file in the project root directory. Put `set new-console on` in the file. Now I'm going to sit back and hope someone has a better solution for the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It works but nerve to switch back and fort between different screen though.